# Records are slight shifted on date plot created using coreplot library

Tags: ios, xamarin, core-plot

Here is a necessary code snippets,

X axis label formatter,

```
NSDateFormatter dateFormatter = new NSDateFormatter();
dateFormatter.DateFormat = "dd/MM";
var timeFormatter = new CPTTimeFormatter(dateFormatter);

timeFormatter.ReferenceDate = NSDate.FromTimeIntervalSinceNow(0);
x.LabelFormatter = timeFormatter;
```

Delegate method of getting records,

```
public override NSNumber NumberForPlot(CPTPlot plot, CPTPlotField forFieldEnum, nuint index)
    {
        if (forFieldEnum == CPTPlotField.ScatterPlotFieldX)
            return new NSNumber((index + 1) * 86400);

        Debug.WriteLine("{0}", Data[(int)index].Rate);
        return Data[(int)index].Rate;
    }
```

See attached screenshot for result looks like. You can see that markers are not aligned to X axis. First data point should display on “01/01” but it is displaying just before it. Same for all other points.

Let me know if anybody wish to look at any other part of code. I just need direction or clue what could lead to this record shifting. I have already looked at sample code provided in coreplot but didn't get any clue on this.

Edit:

Ranges are as below,

```
 plotSpace.XRange = new CPTPlotRange(NSNumber.FromDouble(0).NSDecimalValue, NSNumber.FromDouble(86400 * 9).NSDecimalValue);
 plotSpace.YRange = new CPTPlotRange(NSNumber.FromDouble(-1).NSDecimalValue, NSNumber.FromDouble(9).NSDecimalValue);
```

Also tried,

```
var space = graph.DefaultPlotSpace as CPTXYPlotSpace;
space.ScaleToFitPlots(new CPTPlot [] { dataSourceLinePlot });
```

Edit: [Graph setup code](https://gist.github.com/iducool/fb60f84469b1ae18fe00)

[image]

Comment: 60*60*24 = seconds of a day

Comment: What is the `xRange` for the plot space?

Comment: Added in question. Let me know if required more details

Comment: @EricSkroch: Any clue? I am using xamarin component of CorePlot

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `ReferenceDate` for the time formatter. It is being initialized with the current date and time, so the offset will vary throughout the day depending on when the setup code runs. There are several ways to make an `NSDate` object that corresponds to a fixed time of day. The most straightforward is by using [`NSDateComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/).

Several of the Core Plot example apps, including the "Date Plot" demo in the *Plot Gallery* app, use this technique to generate reference dates.

Also, the automatic axis labeling policy doesn't work well with dates. It's picking tick locations that fall on "nice" numbers of seconds between ticks, but that doesn't correspond to even numbers of days. You should use the fixed interval policy (the default) or one of the ones that let you provide the tick locations directly.

Comment: I have tried same thing. Created date from datecomponent. So, now my date is "2016-01-13 00:00:00 +0000". But no difference in output. Have you noted one more thing from image, as you move ahead on x-Axis difference from from vertical line is increases. It's not same

Comment: Can you post your axis setup code? The `xRange` covers nine days, but the graph only shows six vertical grid lines. It's possible the grid lines are not exactly one day apart.

Comment: Added code link to show whole setup. It could be slight messy now because I have done little experiments with range however graph output is not changing.

Comment: The automatic axis labeling policy doesn't work well with dates. It's picking tick locations that fall on "nice" numbers of seconds between ticks, but that doesn't correspond to even numbers of days. You should use the fixed interval policy (the default) or one of the ones that lets you provide the tick locations directly.

Comment: Thanks fixed interval worked for me. Please update your answer so, I can accept it.